# ClojureScript - How to load user.cljs file for repl sessions

Tags: clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop

I'm starting a cljs repl with a node.js environment.

```
=> clj -m cljs.main -re node
```

Documentation for using the repl says that you can place a **user.cljs** file at the classpath root for the project and it will be automatically loaded into a repl session in the **cljs.user** namespace.

I have a src directory with **user.cljs** at its base. The project's directory structure looks like the following.

```
xyz / deps.edn
    / src / xyz / core.cljs
          / user.cljs
```

ClojureScript version 1.10.520 is the only dependency in deps.edn.

Whenever I start the repl I get the following error.

Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at cljs.closure/compile-file (closure.clj:639).
/var/folders/rk/r65ng3n93l53h95nsvkl265c0000gn/T/out385499094487053918164582825852/cljs/user/user5D28A44.js is not a relative path

When I look in the temporary output folder it is clear that **../cljs/user/user5D28A44.js** is not being generated.

Is this a cljs bug? Can someone show me an example of this working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the ClojureScript repl explicitly from clojure programmatically, the command line startup short hand doesn't work for loading **user.cljs**.

```
=> clj
Clojure 1.10.1
user=> (require '[cljs.repl :as repl])
user=> (require '[cljs.repl.node :as node])
user=> (def env (node/repl-env))
user=> (repl/repl env)
cljs.user=> working?
"Yes."
cljs.user=> ...
```

With the working? symbol defined in **user.cljs** it is available as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a known issue. See: [CLJS-2917](https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/CLJS-2917)

You can work around it by specifying an output directory via `-d`.